# Swift! Present AVPlayerViewController with PreRoll video in a SKScene

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, skscene, avplayerviewcontroller, preroll

I want to present a `AVPlayerViewController` with a pre-roll ad. This is what I have so far:

At the top:

```
let preRollAdPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIG1MsR7zWs")
```

in my didMoveToView:

```
let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
preRollAdPlayer.showsPlaybackControls = true
preRollAdPlayer.player = player
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    preRollAdPlayer.delegate = self
}
```

When a SKSpriteNode is touched:

```
self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(preRollAdPlayer, animated: true, completion: {

    self.preRollAdPlayer.playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler({ (error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("Error Message: %@", error)
        }
    })
    print("preRoll loaded")    
})
```

but when i present this AVPlayerViewController it just looks like this:

[image: Screnshot from iphone]

What am I doing wrong here?